# Smartd unable to send mail

Tags: centos, msmtp, smartmontools

I have a CentOS 8-stream server. I was setting up `smartmontools` to monitor my drives. The MTA is `msmtp`. To test the setup, I modified my `smartd.conf` by adding:

```
/dev/sda -a -m my.mail@pro.vider -M test
```

Since I did not see any mail popping up, I decided to check the journal:

```
journalctl -u smartd
```

which gave the following:

```
smartd[1184]: Executing test of <mail> to my.mail@pro.vider...
smartd[1184]: Test of <mail> to my.mail@pro.vider produced unexpected output (459 bytes) to STDOUT/STDERR:
smartd[1184]: send-mail: cannot connect to smtp.gmail.com, port 587: Permission denied
smartd[1184]: send-mail: could not send mail (account default from /etc/msmtprc)
smartd[1184]: send-mail: cannot log to /var/log/msmtp.log: cannot open: Permission denied
smartd[1184]: send-mail: log info was: host=smtp.gmail.com tls=on auth=on user=my.mail@pro.vider from=my.mail@pro.vider recipients=my.mail@pro.vider errormsg='cannot connect to smtp.gmail.com, port 587: Permission denied' exitcode=EX_TEMPFAIL
```

So, I tried:

```
echo "My message" | mail -s "Some subject" my.mail@pro.vider
```

which does send the mail, but still shows the error:

```
 send-mail: cannot log to /var/log/msmtp.log: cannot open: Permission denied
```

I thought, it might be an issue with SE permissions, so I checked:

```
getsebool -a | grep mail
```

which gave:

```
gitosis_can_sendmail --> off
httpd_can_sendmail --> on
logging_syslogd_can_sendmail --> on
logwatch_can_network_connect_mail --> on
mailman_use_fusefs --> off
postfix_local_write_mail_spool --> on
```

I have two errors, but no idea how to rectify these. Would be glad if someone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Chances are pretty high that it's a selinux issue. Set it to permissive mode and see if it helps. If yes, there are lots of tutorials on how to allow the disallowed operations.

Answer (score 0):

> send-mail: cannot connect to smtp.gmail.com, port 587: Permission denied
> send-mail: could not send mail (account default from /etc/msmtprc)

This is probably an authentication problem, check your credentials in your `/etc/msmtprc`.

> send-mail: cannot log to /var/log/msmtp.log: cannot open: Permission denied

It could be AppArmor forbidding to log to `/var/log/msmtp.log`.

I don't know about CentOS, but you might want to take a look at [this AskUbuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/878288/msmtp-cannot-write-to-var-log-msmtp-msmtp-log) anyway. On Ubuntu there is a default AppArmor profile that only allows logging to `/var/log/msmtp` (without the `.log` extention).

Or you can try with `syslog LOG_MAIL` (which should log to `/var/log/mail.log`) instead of `logfile /var/log/msmtp.log` in your msmtprc, as suggested [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/msmtp/+bug/1876496).

Comment: There is no AppArmor on CentOS.